# Selectyze is not working if data is loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery, dom, select

I'm using Selectyze plugin http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/selectyze to style the select menus. I've 2 items to select : the first contains main items and the second contains subitems belong to the items from the first menu. When then first menu changes it fetches data from the database via ajax and embed the data in the second select menu. But when I chose any new data from the second menu the script doesn't work and returns # instead of choosing the subitem and closing the menu. Here's the simple ajax code and it works without any problem and subitems are displayed

```
var ajax2 = false;
        ajax2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax2.open('GET','ajax/getsubitems.php?item='+item);
        ajax2.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(ajax2.readyState==4 && ajax2.status==200){
                var result = ajax2.responseText;
                $(".DivSelectyze.grey3 ul").html(result);
            }
        }
        ajax2.send(null);
```

Data from inspect element:

```
<select name="neighbour" id="choose_neighbour" class="selectyze3" style="display: none;">
<option value="subitem1">subitem1</option>
<option value="subitem2">subitem2</option>
</select>

<div class="DivSelectyze grey3" style="z-index: 9989;">
<a href="#" rel="" class="selectyzeValue">choose</a>
<ul class="UlSelectize" style="display: block;">
<li><a href="#" rel="subitem1">subitem1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" rel="subitem2">subitem2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

If the data is loaded with the dom it works but with ajax it does not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Isn't enough to $('.UlSelectize').Selectyze({..}); after data load?

Comment: this code is already in the page and works with items loaded with the DOM